# passing different type variable for where clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to print `$data2['hasil2']` result, but the result just print empty array `Array ( )`. Could anyone tell me how the correct way to passing `$data1` and `$semester` in tampilSos function?

```
public function insertOrtu(){
    $Semester= $_POST['Semester'];
    $person=$this->session->userdata('idperson');
    $data1=$this->M_Ortu->tampilIdsiswa($person);
    $data2['hasil2']=$this->M_Ortu->tampilSos($data1, $Semester);
    print_r($data2['hasil2']);
}
```

here my model

```
public function tampilIdsiswa($person){
        $this->db->select('idsiswa');
        $this->db->from('siswa a');
        $this->db->join('siswa_kelas b','a.induk=b.induk','left');
        $this->db->where('idperson',$person);
        $data=$this->db->get();
        return $data->row()->idsiswa;
    }

    public function tampilSos($idsiswa, $semester){
        $array = array('idsiswa' => $idsiswa, 'kdSemester' => $semester, 'kdmapel'=>'sos');
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('nilai_siswa a');
        $this->db->join('master_nilai b','a.idnilai=b.idnilai','right');
        $this->db->where($array);
        $data = $this->db->get();
        return $data->result();
    }
```

Comment: i think here, return $res = $data->row_array(); return $res['idsiswa']

Comment: try with this : `$this->db->join('master_nilai b','b.idnilai = a.idnilai','right');` and make sure you have data with corresponding query in your tables

Comment: @SanjayKumar its a different way of doing the same thing he is currently doing. would yield same results.

Comment: Leny, you should always check num_rows() before accessing the result object. Return false or something if there are no rows and handle a false return accordingly. this is good practice and makes your code easier to debug/more maintainable and prevents errors

Comment: yeah i finally found my mistake. i just not look my code carefully enough.. thx for ur help guys.